# Sum SQL Column by Date for different Accounts

Tags: c#, sql

I want to display Total Balance for different accounts by Date.  I have the output of a SQL query with these columns (Account, Date(DateTime), Balance).  I'm using .NET Chart and want to display Date on the X Axis and Total Balance on the Y Axis.  For the below data, the data points should be (2013-12-08 17:00, 1800), (2013-12-08 17:01, 1000), (2013-12-08 17:02, 1600).  I've tried filling a DataTable with the data but then I need to query it to display.  Any ideas?

```
Account    Date                   Balance
A          2013-12-08 17:00:37    500 
B          2013-12-08 17:00:42    600
C          2013-12-08 17:00:44    700
D          2013-12-08 17:00:46    800
A          2013-12-08 17:01:22    100
B          2013-12-08 17:01:24    200
C          2013-12-08 17:01:28    300
D          2013-12-08 17:01:37    400
A          2013-12-08 17:02:20    100
B          2013-12-08 17:02:25    300
C          2013-12-08 17:02:28    500
D          2013-12-08 17:02:30    700
```

Comment: What DBMS and version are you using?

Comment: How did you get `1800` for `17:00`? Shouldn't it be `2600`?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: "SQL" is not the name of a database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer on MS SQL is similar, with a slight difference in the date formatting to get the grouping resolution you want:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, [Date]), 120),16)), AVG([Balance])
FROM data
GROUP BY CONVERT(DATETIME, LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, [Date]), 120),16))
```

Since Microsoft's T-SQL prior to v110 (SQL Server 2012) doesn't have a decent date formatting function built in, the above uses the [`CONVERT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) function to get the datetime in `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` format and discards the seconds before converting back to a `DATETIME` value for grouping and output.  This should give you a grouping at the level of individual minutes.

Of course if you *want* the date in string form, remove the outer `CONVERT` statements from both the `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` lists.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL solution:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%c-%%d %H:%i'), SUM(balance)
FROM data
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%c-%%d %H:%i')
```

returns

```
DATE_FORMAT(DATE, '%Y-%C-%%D %H:%I')    SUM(BALANCE)
2013-12-%d 17:00                        2600
2013-12-%d 17:01                        1000
2013-12-%d 17:02                        1600
```

SqlFiddle demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9b59a/8

Answer (score 0):

@marcinjuraszek's answer for SQL Server 2012:

```
SELECT FORMAT(date, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm'), SUM(balance)
FROM data
GROUP BY FORMAT(date, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm')
```

Comment: That works on MS SQL Server 2012 only.  Earlier versions of MS SQL do not have a `FORMAT` function.

Comment: Yup, thats why I said SQL Server 2012 in the answer since the OP didn't specify a DBMS or version.

Comment: Fair enough then... I saw `FORMAT` and reacted.  Ignore my prior comment :P